# read text file as csv in vb.net

Tags: connection-string, vb.net-2010

am using vb.net .am having a file. that file contain some values . i want to read that file using vb.net.

```
file name cdr_StandAloneCluster_03_201208090909_33121.file

data type        file

it contain the data look like this


cdrRecordType,"globalCallID_callManagerId","globalCallID_callId","origLegCallIdentifier","dateTimeOrigination","origNodeId","origSpan","origIpAddr","callingPartyNumber","callingPartyUnicodeLoginUserID","origCause_location","origCause_value","origPrecedenceLevel","origMediaTransportAddress_IP","origMediaTransportAddress_Port","origMediaCap_payloadCapability","origMediaCap_maxFramesPerPacket","origMediaCap_g723BitRate","origVideoCap_Codec","origVideoCap
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to parsing your dta is to use the "SPLIT" method

Here is a sample code i knocked up.
I cannot be sure its 110% but it ought to bring you a lot closer to resolving your issue.

```
    Sub SomePrcoedure(strFilename As String)

Dim arrRawData As Generic.List(Of String) = Nothing
Dim arrLineItems() As String = Nothing
Dim objStreamReader As StreamReader = Nothing
Dim datTextLine As String = Nothing

    '-> Validate Filename
    If Trim(strFilename) <> "" Then
        If FileIO.FileSystem.FileExists(strFilename) Then
            '-> Read the WHOLE file in 
            arrRawData = New Generic.List(Of String)
            objStreamReader = New StreamReader(Trim(strFilename))
            Do
                datTextLine = objStreamReader.ReadLine()
                If Trim(datTextLine) <> "" Then
                    arrRawData.Add(Trim(datTextLine))
                End If
            Loop Until objStreamReader.EndOfStream()
            objStreamReader.Close()
            '-> Split EACH line data into the array arrLineItems
            For intCounta = 0 To arrRawData.Count - 1
                arrLineItems = Split(arrRawData(intCounta), ",")
                'your line is now split into the array arrLineItems() 
                'process results here or store results for later or your code here....
            Next
        Else
            'file not found
        End If
    Else
        'file name missing
    End If
    arrRawData = Nothing
    arrLineItems = Nothing
    objStreamReader = Nothing
    datTextLine = Nothing

End Sub
```